# Snowflake SQL error: Insert query: expecting DATE but got NUMBER(9,0) for column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting DATE but got NUMBER(9,0) for column Invoice_Date

I tried `TO_DATE(Invoice_Date)` and `DATE(Invoice_Date)`, but still get the same error...  Please let me know if there is something else I can try.

Here's the format of the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO UBS_STAGE.STAGE_BILLING
(
    INVOICE_DATE
)
SELECT INVOICE_DATE
FROM BSCHEMA.BTABLE;
```

The column type in BTABLE is DATE and sample data is as follows:

```
2019-05-7
2019-05-22
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Edit your question and provide an example of the SQL you are running and some sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in a number, you need to cast it to a string first, and then tell Snowflake what the format of the date is.  So, something along these lines (making assumptions on your number format):

```
DATE(numberfield::varchar,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: Mike,  Thank you for your response.  I tried this and am still getting the same error.  I just edited my question to include more information...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just cast this as a date:

```
select column1::date 
from values ('2019-05-7'),('2019-05-22');
```

Returns:

```
COLUMN1::DATE
2019-05-07
2019-05-22
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did try this and am still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

are the datatype of the columns Date in both the tables, because i tried and this worked for me.

```
create table STAGE_BILLING ( INVOICE_DATE date)
insert into STAGE_BILLING values(current_date())
select * from STAGE_BILLING
create table BTABLE(INVOICE_DATE  date);
INSERT INTO STAGE_BILLING ( INVOICE_DATE ) SELECT INVOICE_DATE FROM BTABLE; 
select * from STAGE_BILLING
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  yes - the datatype is Date in both tables.  I ran your code and that worked in my environment as well...

Comment: Try with to_timestamp_ntz(INVOICE_DATE)  and see if that works.